# jQuery mouseenter() is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter

So I have this simple HTML

```
<div class="song">
    <img src="http://o.scdn.co/300/40e3ec60c92513f724f47ce71baad1e496627107">
</div>
```

And this simple jQuery

```
$(".song").on( "mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).css( "background-color", "red" );
    alert('bla');
});
```

And the event does not fire.

Although

```
$(".naujienuKategorija").on( "mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

Works just fine on

```
<p class="naujienuKategorija">Apklausa</p>
```

Which is on the same page.

.song has the following css

```
.song {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I am obviously missing something... obvious.

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: It works fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/NY8L7/

Comment: is your `.song` code in the same block/location as the `.nauj...` code? i ask because it's possible the code is generated before the dom is ready (which obviously isn't the case for `.nauj...`)

Comment: works here too - also made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5vKKc/

Comment: Did you bind the `mouseenter` event inside of `$(document).ready`?

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Worked fine here on Chromium v25 and all jquery versions on jsfiddle  except  1.6.4 http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/RYSP2/

Comment: Does the image have height?  For example it's not being floated inside .song?  Could be worth trying to target .song>img and see if that helps.

Comment: @Ian I do not know what is wrong, but binding it inside `$(document).ready` has solved it! So if you'll answer, I'll accept it. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for an event to be bound to an element, the element has to be ready and found. A general way to do this is to put your event bindings inside of `$(document).ready` because it ensures original elements on the page can be accessed. So use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".song").on( "mouseenter", function() {
        $(this).css( "background-color", "red" );
        alert('bla');
    });
});
```

Another option is to put your event binding on the page at any time **after** the target elements, either immediately or right before the `</body>`. For example:

```
<div class="song"></div>
<div class="song></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".song").on("mouseenter", function () {

    });
</script>
```

It might've been working with the `.naujienuKategorija` elements because you were using the second method above, but weren't with the `.song` elements.